# SharedPreferences в Android

Tags: java, android

Я получаю с сервера `id` пользователя и сохраняю через `SharedPreference`. 
Возможно ли использовать это `id` в условии `if else` ?
Мне это нужно для загрузочного экрана.

```
if ( id == cуществует в памяти устройства) { 
   загружаем activity A
}
else { activity B }
```

update.
код `SharedPreferences` создаваемый в `activity A`

```
//Записываем user_data в файл настроек
public void onPutSettings(){
    final String SAVED_USER = "saved_user";
    SharedPreferences sPref = getSharedPreferences(SAVED_USER, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_USER, key.getText().toString());
    ed.putString(SAVED_USER, id_user.getText().toString());
    ed.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this, "User saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Возможно. В чем проблема?

Comment: Каким образом получить Id пользователя в загрузочном экране(Splash) непонятно. Так как SharedPreference создается в Activity A, B.
Использовать static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SharedPreference` создается при [первом вызове](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)) `getSharedPreferences()` и не важно в каком `Activity` этот код вызывается.
Так же методы `get...()` у объекта `SharedPreference` могут принимать дефолтные значения, которые будут возвращаться в случае если в `SharedPreference` не найдена запись с переданным ключом. Таким образом можно передать в метод какое то дефолтное значение и сравнивать с ним то, что вернул метод. Ниже код, реализующий это:

```
SharedPreferences sPref = getSharedPreferences(SAVED_USER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String id = sPref.getString(SAVED_USER, "default value");

if("default value".equals(id)){
    // activity B
} else {
    // загружаем activity A
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @P.Dm еще заметил что вы в SharedPreference сохраняете 2 разных значения по 1 ключу. Я так думаю это не то что вы хотите.

Comment: Нужна была авторизация без ввода почты и паролей, второй ключ это пароль, который генерируется автоматически и добавляется в БД на сервере, там ему присваивается id_user. В дальнейшем нужен только id_user.